# Printing a number with either one decimal place or none

Tags: printing, numbers, decimal

Is there a simple way to print a number with either one decimal place or none?
I've searched the net for a method to do that but all of them try to always have a zero after the decimal point..
I want 3.0 to be printed as just 3, and 3.5 to be printed as 3.5.
I tried `print('{:.1f}'.format(num))` but this prints 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the programming language, so I will provide an answer in [pseudocode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).

**Using if-else**

```
printWithOneOrNoDecimals(n)
  if (isNumberInteger(n))
    printWithoutDecimals(n)
  else
    printNumberWithOneDecimal(n)

isNumberInteger(n)
  return round(n) == n
```

The method round(n) should round the number, for example 2.4 to 2. Because 2.4 != 2, isNumberInteger(2.4) would return false and the else statement is exectuted.

Now you can define different formats for printing numbers with or without decimal in printNumberWithOneDecimal and printWithoutDecimals.

**Using “right trim” or “right strip”**

Another way to achieve the result is to first make the number a string (maybe formatting it to have one decimal) and then “trimming” or “stripping” it from the right, first “all” zeros (in your case at most one) and then the decimal point (if any on the right). Note: trim or strip methods do not give an error if there’s nothing to trim/strip.

I guess that in Python it would be:

```
'{:.1f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Happy coding, good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much!

I thought there might be a simpler way to do that in python that I was missing..

Comment: I know little of Python. You could try make it a string and then “trim” or “strip” from the right, like this: str(n).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')

Comment: I have updated my answer.